# Bootstrap 4. Не работает стили с index.css

Tags: css, bootstrap, bootstrap4

Стили с моего `index.css` работают некорректно. Точнее, заданные стили стандартным тегам HTML работают, но, например, у меня есть id #contacts и стили заданные ему не отображаются даже в стилях хрома.

Вот код: подключение bootstrap

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-WskhaSGFgHYWDcbwN70/dfYBj47jz9qbsMId/iRN3ewGhXQFZCSftd1LZCfmhktB" crossorigin="anonymous">
```

Подключение `index.css` (ниже на пару строчек)

```
<link href="styles/index.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

P.S. !important не помогает
Пример index.html

```
<footer style="background-color: aqua;">
    <div class="container" id="contacts">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-4">
                <img border="0" src="resourses/ico-pntu.ico" alt="logo_univer">
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-8">
                <ul>
                    <li style="list-style-type:none; text-align: center;"><h4>Контакти</h4></li>
                    <li><strong>АДРЕСА:</strong> м. Полтава, Першотравневий проспект, 24. Корпус Ф, к.121, 122, 123</li>
                    <li><strong>ТЕЛ:</strong> (053)227-38-57</li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</footer>
```

Пример index.css

```
#contacts {
    font-family: monospace !important;
}
```

в итоге шрифт в теге c id `contacts` не изменяется

Comment: Ванговать??? Смоделируйте вашу проблему.  Сделайте пример кода на https://jsfiddle.net/ , Да сам сток это умеете делать (разместить ваш пример кода) Ошибкой может быть банальная опечатка в ваших стилях

Comment: пожалуйста держите

Comment: Это что? http://take.ms/UPHff

Comment: Я ж говорю - опечатки. Удалите звёздочки. ![Alt text](https://monosnap.com/image/Ji5ZlElnKrOcUmZimTfvoVRbuuBOQT.png)

Comment: это я в редакторе пытался выделить айдишник жирным шрифтом.хех, в исходнике их нет.извини что ввел в заблуждение

Comment: Странно. Всё-равно, где-то закралась опечатка. Хотя я использовал полный копипаст вашего кода http://jsfiddle.net/vjdsLygc/

Comment: просто вот что интересно, в даном проекте стандартные теги работают на ура, а мои классы или айдишники нет. #contacts не единичный случай

Comment: Добавьте весь ваш файл `index.css` к вопросу, полюбому там опечатка.

Comment: вот пожалуйста весь index.css

`body{
    background-color: white;
}

.main-nav{
    position: relative;
}

.shadow img{
    margin: 50px;
}

footer{
    background-color: aqua;
}

#contacts{
    font-family: monospace;!important;
}`

Comment: @mara1esh если есть возможность, дайте ссылку на пациента. А то так только по кофейной гуще гадать.

Comment: Уважаемый @andrybak, вы не заметили просьбы в комментариях к моему ответу?

Comment: на всякий случай: `font-family: monospace; !important;` -- @mara1esh, здесь лишняя точка с запятой. Маркер `!important` должен быть до точки с запятой вместе с аттрибутом, к которому применяется, вот так `font-family: monospace !important;`